# Rust ffi include dynamic library in cross platform fashion

Tags: rust, cross-platform, rust-cargo

I would like to include a dynamic C library in Rust with FFI.

The library is actually also build with Rust, but exposes a C interface, so that it can be used from other languages, too. When I build the library (type: `cdylib`) with cargo I get a `.dylib` on MacOS and a `.dll` as well as a `.dll.lib` file on windows. These libraries also get different names, derived from the project name (`libmy_lib.dylib` on MacOS and `my_lib.dll` as well as `my_lib.dll.lib` on Windows).

I would like to reference these files in a cross-platform way. Because currently I have to use

```rust
#[link(name = "my_lib.dll", kind = "dylib")]
```

on windows, whereas on MacOS I need to use

```rust
#[link(name = "my_lib", kind = "dylib")]
```

I have already tried to rename the `my_lib.dll.lib` to `my_lib.lib`, but I still get a Linker Error, saying

`LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'my_lib.lib'`

How can I reference the files, so that I can use my code for Mac and Windows? If thats only possible with `cfg_attr` tags I would also accept that. <s>Ideally I would also like to get rid of the `.lib` file for windows if possible.</s>

Comment: Getting rid of the import library (`.lib`) on Windows means that you're exchanging [Load-Time Dynamic Linking](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/load-time-dynamic-linking) for [Run-Time Dynamic Linking](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/run-time-dynamic-linking). The latter requires that you write or generate code to resolve symbols. That code can fail, and you're now going to have to handle errors, too. It's much easier, cleaner, and less error-prone to just let the OS loader resolve the imports and deal with errors before your code gets a chance to run.

Comment: I see. I think it's better to leave it as is then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this

### Libloading

You could use crate [libloading](https://crates.io/crates/libloading)

Example:

```rust
let lib = unsafe {
    #[cfg(unix)]
    let path = "mylib.so";
    #[cfg(windows)]
    let path = "mylib.dll";
    libloading::Library::new(path).expect("Failed to load library")
};
let func: libloading::Symbol<unsafe extern fn() -> u32> = unsafe {
     lib.get(b"my_func").expect("Failed to load function `my_func`")
};
// Can call func later while `lib` in scope
```

### Conditional compilations

You need different attributes on `extern` block depending on your target. This can be achieved using [`cfg_attr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg_attr-attribute) attribute. It would select different attributes depending on target.

```rust
#[cfg_attr(windows, link(name = "my_lib.dll", kind = "dylib"))]
#[cfg_attr(unix, link(name = "my_lib.so", kind = "dylib"))]
extern "C" {
    fn sum(a: u32, b: u32)->u64;
}
```

Comment: Does that force me to use Run-Time Dynamic Linking?
Also I kind of dislike, that the exported functions won't be available globally and only when e.g. `lib` is in scope. Apart from that I would have liked to get around using another dependency just for this...

Comment: @fra Yes, this requires runtime dynamic linking, that's what [Library::get](https://docs.rs/libloading/0.7.0/libloading/struct.Library.html#method.get) does. And yes, it introduces complexity by having you write code, and even more so by having to find an appropriate time to load the library and making the symbols globally available. Lazy statics might be an option, but that just adds a failure mode, turning *all* imports into fallible operations.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I found a temporary solution for this now.

I used this pattern:

```rust
#[cfg(windows)]
#[link(name = "my_lib.dll", kind = "dylib")]
extern {
    // Reference the exported functions
}

#[cfg(unix)]
#[link(name = "my_lib", kind = "dylib")]
extern {
    // Reference the exported functions
}
```

I don't like it that much, because I had to define the very same `extern{}` block twice, but it works and I could also extend this pattern to for example use `#[cfg(target_os = "macos")]` if needed...

EDIT: Thanks to @Angelicos Phosphoros I improved the code a bit by using a macro like so:

```rust
/// Import native functions with the Rust FFI
macro_rules! import_native_functions {
    () => {
        // Reference the exported functions
    };
}

#[cfg(windows)]
#[link(name = "my_lib.dll", kind = "dylib")]
extern {
    import_native_functions!();
}


#[cfg(unix)]
#[link(name = "my_lib", kind = "dylib")]
extern {
    import_native_functions!();
}
```

Comment: You could try to avoid duplication using macros.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. It seemed like a good idea, however for some reason I was not able to get it to work. At that point I am just curious, because I almost feel like this is a limitation / bug in the rust compiler...

Comment: Unfortunitely, you probably should use something like procedural macros. https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html#function-like-procedural-macros Something like this (notice: I didn't tried it): https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1cf9f5657618db3f734233a15c525e52

Comment: I reconsidered what I did, and realized, that I might as well work around this, by putting the macro inside the `extern` block, so I did that. If somebody has any idea, how to remove all the platform checks, though I will happily make that the accepted answer...

Comment: Hi @frankenapps ! I found a better way to do this (see my answer).